# How to resolve Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key ""in scala code?

Tags: java, scala

I have some code in scala:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
if (args.length < 1) {
  println("Must specify the path to config file ")
  println("Usage progname <path to config file> ")
  return
}
val url = args(0)
val config = ConfigFactory.load(url)
val host = config.getString(hostname)
val conf = new SparkConf(true).setAppName(appName)
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", host)
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

logger.info("Got the path as %s".format(url))
(sc, config)
.....
.....
```

but when I tried to run, getting following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'MyTestCode'
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:147)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:206)
at com.test.replicator.events.MyTestCode$.main(MyTestCode.scala:45)
at com.test.replicator.events.MyTestCode.main(MyTestCode.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

The error is comming in line no. 45 which is

```
val host = config.getString(hostname)
```

How to resolve the problem. Is it Jar not found problem or code error?

Comment: Why is it looking for the key 'MyTestCode' ? Could you print the value of url and hostname? Just to be sure that they are what you expect.

Comment: Yes, I still do not understand why the name of the class is used as a key. I have never used the typesafe library though...

Comment: How do you set `hostname`?

Comment: val appName = getClass.getSimpleName.dropRight(1)
  val hostname = appName + ".cassandrahost"

Comment: {
    "MyTestCode": {
    "keyspace": "mytestDb",
    "table": "abc",
    "cassandrahost" : "xx.xx.xx.xx",   
  }
}

@Marco Altiri - "MyTestCode" is a Key in input file.

Comment: Could you add in your post the content of the conf file? It seems to me that either the file cannot be read or its content is incorrect.